# AWS async SQS queue functionality raising error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, amazon-sqs

I have the below code but when I run it I get the error at the bottom of the description. Does anybody know what is wrong with code?

```
import asyncio
import os
import aioboto3
from typing import Dict, List

from src.data.models.post_webinar.lead_classes import OutreachProspect, SalesforceCampaignMember

class AsyncCommunicator:

    async def async_signal_flow(self, campaign_members: List[SalesforceCampaignMember]):
        tasks = []
        for cm in campaign_members:
            cm = cm.as_json()
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._send_signal_to_sqs_queue("SIGNAL_PROCESSING_QUEUE", cm))
        tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    async def async_sequence(self, prospects: List[OutreachProspect], webinar_uuid: str):
        tasks = []
        for prospect in prospects:
            prospect = prospect.as_json()
            prospect["webinar_uuid"] = webinar_uuid
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(self._send_signal_to_sqs_queue("SEQUENCE_PROCESSING_QUEUE", prospect))
            tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    
    @staticmethod
    async def _send_signal_to_sqs_queue(queue_name: str, serialized_object: Dict) -> None:
        session = aioboto3.Session()
        async with session.resource('sqs') as sqs_client:
            queue = await sqs_client.get_queue_by_name(
                QueueName=os.environ[queue_name]
            )
            await queue.send_message(
                MessageBody=str(serialized_object)
        )
```

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": "AttributeError(\"'ClientCreatorContext' object has no attribute 'meta'\")"
}
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AioSession._create_client' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I'm quite new to async and I've gotten as far as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Good Evening, I checked your code and the error that is being shown. I guess using "aioboto3.Session" might be creating issues; can you try with "aioboto3.client"?

Also,I noticed that, You are appending tasks to the `tasks` list outside of the for-loop, which will result in only the last task being awaited. To fix this, move the `tasks.append(task)` line inside the for-loop.

Comment: Thanks for assisting - I fixed the append but still not getting that far as I get same error with client:

sqs_queue\n    async with session.resource('sqs') as sqs_client:\n               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\nAttributeError: 'ClientCreatorContext' object has no attribute 'resource'","exception_name":"AttributeError"}

{
    "success": false,
    "error": "AttributeError(\"'ClientCreatorContext' object has no attribute 'resource'\")"
}
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AioSession._create_client' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: The error message represent that the sqs_client variable is not of th e type SQSClient.

have you checked the documentation? **https://pypi.org/project/aioboto3/**